# C# Default parameters specifiers not permitted visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am encountering a weird problem. Though I am using Visual Studio 2010 and targeting .Net 4.0 in my project, I keep receiver this error from the compiler "Default parameter specifiers are not permitted" for the following line of code:

```
public object GetContractCompSett(string compID, bool calcItemRoot = false, bool isSale = true) 
{
  ....
}
```

While searching on the web (and on stackoverflow), the solutions point to the fact that name parameters and default value are a features of .Net 4 (the error is raised when targeting .Net  3.5 and below). But in my case, my compiler is set for .Net 4.0 still I receive this error. (I have spent the whole day trying to fix it....)
Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are targeting an older C# version.  Project + Properties, Build tab, scroll down, Advanced button, Language Version setting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my settings are correct. I have fully checked it. I'm targeting .Net 4. Anyway after having wasted 2 days of my limited time on this project, I have resolved to uninstall and reinstall visual studio (...sigh...)

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your target framework to 3.5 then back to 4. That worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9042847/2124709) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10097625/2124709).

Comment: Thanks Gojira for your input. I have tried your solution with no luck. I have resolved to uninstall and reinstall visual studio...(seems like something deeper has been corrupted...)