# .NET build using Jenkins MSBuild error "Default parameter specifiers are not permitted"

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, .net-3.5, default-parameters

I am trying to build a .NET project that I have no idea how it works through MSbuild plugin in Jenkins.Anyhow, this targets framework 3.5 and that what I use in my build server. As I build I get the following error with no idea how to resolve..

```
 "c:\jenkins\workspace\Master.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"c:\jenkins\workspace\FactivaWebUI01-Fornax\UIVirtualServices\UIVirtualServices.csproj" (default target) (16) ->
(CoreCompile target) -> 
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\CommunicatorAuthorService.cs(36,78): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\CommunicatorAuthorService.cs(66,33): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\CommunicatorAuthorService.cs(67,29): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\CommunicatorAuthorService.cs(68,29): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\CommunicatorAuthorService.cs(69,28): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\CommunicatorAuthorService.cs(70,43): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\CommunicatorAuthorService.cs(71,41): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\CommunicatorAuthorService.cs(72,37): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\CommunicatorAuthorService.cs(73,56): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\CommunicatorAuthorService.cs(156,85): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\ICommunicatorAuthorService.cs(32,33): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\ICommunicatorAuthorService.cs(33,29): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\ICommunicatorAuthorService.cs(34,29): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\ICommunicatorAuthorService.cs(35,28): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\ICommunicatorAuthorService.cs(36,43): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\ICommunicatorAuthorService.cs(37,41): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\ICommunicatorAuthorService.cs(38,37): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Authors\ICommunicatorAuthorService.cs(39,56): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Charts\CommunicatorChartService.cs(54,68): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted
  CSP\Communicator\Charts\CommunicatorChartService.cs(54,109): error CS0241: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted

    184 Warning(s)
    20 Error(s)
```

the funny thing is that when I use visual studio 2013 to build the same project it builds just about fine.

csproj file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <StartPageUrl>
          </StartPageUrl>
          <StartAction>CurrentPage</StartAction>
          <AspNetDebugging>True</AspNetDebugging>
          <SilverlightDebugging>False</SilverlightDebugging>
          <NativeDebugging>False</NativeDebugging>
          <SQLDebugging>False</SQLDebugging>
          <ExternalProgram>
          </ExternalProgram>
          <StartExternalURL>
          </StartExternalURL>
          <StartCmdLineArguments>
          </StartCmdLineArguments>
          <StartWorkingDirectory>
          </StartWorkingDirectory>
          <EnableENC>False</EnableENC>
          <AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>True</AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

So as per suggestion, I try and build it with MsBuild 4.0 only to receive the following error:

```
(GenerateSerializationAssembliesForAllTypes target) -> 
  SGEN : error : An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll. [c:\jenkins\workspace\FactivaWebUI01-Fornax\MessageModel\MessageModel.csproj]

    129 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suspect that your .NET project does not, in fact, target the C# version included in .NET Framework 3.5 but rather C# 4.0, which is included in .NET Framework 4. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6398438/287610) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7823931/287610), for example, where the same error is discussed. There is a good answer regarding [the C# compiler versions and corresponding .NET Framework versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247623/287610).

Can you provide the framework targeting information from your .NET project's `.csproj` project file to verify? It's an XML file and you should find the target framework information very near the top, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <!-- Some elements omitted -->
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

**UPDATE:** Thank you for providing your `.csproj` file. That helps quite a bit. Notice in that file, the targeted .NET Framework version is 3.5 (`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>`). Now, *because you have C# 4.0 code* in your project (such as the default parameters that you were getting warnings about), you *must* use the C# 4.0 compiler *and* **update the target framework version to 4.0** (or higher). You can do this most safely via the project properties in Visual Studio. I wouldn't recommend editing the `.csproj` file by hand.

In short, your problem is due to the fact that *using MSBuild 4.0 is not enough to compile the project against the 4.0 framework.* It may use the newer compiler, which takes care of some (but not all!) of the language features, but it will not update the assemblies that your project uses.

Comment: Well, that certainly cleared up a few errors and warnings. :) Now, why on earth would it be trying to load the .NET 2.0 mscorlib?
Can you please, instead of providing only a part of your `.csproj` file, provide the entire thing? Only remove any included source file references (compiled and content files) if you feel the need to, but **everything else is important** in this case. (And you did not provide the part which we really needed, the first time around.) We're looking for the project target framework version and references, to start with.